# Flash 11.2.202.228 audio choppy/stutters

Tags: 11.10, flash

The other day my system was upgraded to using Flash 11.2.202.228.
Since then I have had a slight "stutter" or "choppy" audio on playbacks. I would guess it is a buffer under run problem.

Anyone knows what has happened with the new flash-release?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

well, it seems like there is a bug in Flash version 11.2.202.228. [[launchpad]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+bug/968759)

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11823501#post11823501) I did find some clues.
So I downloaded the previous version (available from Abode as binaries), replaced by existing `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`with the one from the previous version.

And now sounds is working like a charm again.

Also, when the next flash upgrade comes along, the automatic upgrade should as normal.

Comment: Which version worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Switch from Unity to Unity 2D ("Ubuntu 2D" on the login screen).

I did this and I can now play full-screen Flash video with no audio stutter.

Before I switched, Flash audio would stutter.

This is on 12.04 LTS 32-bit, on a Pentium T2600 with 3GB RAM, and version `11.2.202.235ubuntu0.12.04.1` of the `flashplugin-installer` package.